# How to hide certain columns in tree view based on selection field value?

Tags: xml, odoo-10

I want to hide some fields based on the selection field .The fields are in tree view. neither the code 
`attrs="{'invisible':[('od_term_line','not in',('month'))]}"`

nor `invisible="context.get('od_term_line','quart')"`, #quarts is the selection value in which the value should not be shown

`invisible="context.get('od_term_line')!='month'"` works

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To use like this firstly you have to store the selection fields value in list then put the condition in attrs.
It will surely work.
Thanks

```
    #In python file.
    year = fields.Selection("put the all months here.")
    list1 = []
    for every_month in year:
        list1.append(every_month):


    <!--then condition like this in XML-->
<field attrs="{'invisible':[('january','not in',('year'))]}"/>
```